# Is there a difference between np.matrix(np.array([0,0])) and np.matrix([0,0])?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I was reading this [code](https://www.johnwittenauer.net/machine-learning-exercises-in-python-part-1/), for implementing linear regression from scratch:

```
# convert from data frames to numpy matrices
X = np.matrix(X.values)
y = np.matrix(y.values)
theta = np.matrix(np.array([0,0]))
```

When I came across this line:

```
np.matrix(np.array([0,0]))
```

I was wondering why didn't the person just write `np.matrix([0,0])`.

I ran both in jupyter notebook and got the same output:

```
theta = np.matrix([0,0])
theta2 = np.matrix(np.array([0,0]))
print(theta,theta2,type(theta),type(theta2))
```

Output:`[[0 0]] [[0 0]] <class 'numpy.matrix'> <class 'numpy.matrix'>`

Is there a difference between the two? Does the extra `np.array` somehow part add to the functionality of theta? Will the final code function properly if I replace the former with the latter?

Comment: That was written in 2014.  Now `np.matrix` has a PendingDepricationWarning.  I expect that demo author was just using a coding style that he was used to, without fine tuning from a bunch of SO readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weirdly enough, `matrix(array([0,0]))` creates a clean object that owns its data

```
>>> np.matrix(np.array([0,0])).flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
>>> np.matrix(np.array([0,0])).base
```

whereas `matrix([0,0])` appears to be a view into an anonymous array.

```
>>> np.matrix([0,0]).flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
>>> np.matrix([0,0]).base
array([0, 0])
```

So, the extra `array` in `matrix(array(..))` seems to avoid clutter, though the deeper reasons for that remain mysterious to me.

Comment: `np.matrix` has `copy=True` parameter, `np.asmatrix` has default False copy.  The `matrix.__new__` returns the `ndarray` input according to this copy (along with a final shape adjustment).  Other `data` has go through a `np.array(data, ...)` followed by a `ndarray.__new__` call.  Look at the numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py code for more details.

Comment: In effect, both use `np.array` to turn the list into an array.  The rest is just casting that array into the `matrix` subclass.  Starting from a large list, I don't see significant timing differences (even compared to the plain `np.array(alist)`.).  We can also use `arr.view(np.matrix)``.

Answer (score 1):

You may check the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html):

The signature "data" of `np.matrix` can be either array_like or string, while both [0,0] and its corresponding `numpy.ndarray` counterpart suffice.